# Magento: How to see my language in the URL

Tags: php, magento

I'm working with magento languages and I don't know how I can see the language in my url, for example.

```
www.shop.com/de
www.shop.com/fr
www.shop.com/es
```

because now I can change the language but the url don't change.

Answer (score 4):

You can include the store codes in the url. 
Go to `System->Configuration->Web->Url Options` and set the field `Add Store Code to Urls` to `Yes`.
You also have to make sure that the codes for your store views are `de, en and es`

Comment: If you own the localized domain name you can override the base unsecure and secure URL's for each store view and potentially have www.shop.com, www.shop.de, www.shop.fr etc. If you just want the store code then use setting explained above.